# Help identify bmx bike by logo stamp

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx, badge

[image]Stamps is like a shield with two bones crossing making a x

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Photos of the rest of the bike might also help, at least by narrowing down the range of years in question.